# Android button and the size of text

Tags: android, button, text-size

I have a layout with a few buttons that takes the space of the entire layout using weight properties.
Each button has some text on it with a fixed size which is set by android:textSize="30dp" so on a screen size of a small mobile device (A phone) the text's size if about the size of the button. But on a large device (A tablet) the button size expands yet the text size remains the same (30dp).

I want the button size and text size ratio to be maintained in every resolution, can it be done using the layout XML code? I would like to avoid doing it programmatically.

Comment: using weight will always modify element size. since you are using a fixed value for text and variable value for button it will never work. i would recommend fixed value for button also.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is very simple

You should use a dimension.xml with diferent sizes each density/size and place it on:

- values-mdpi
- Values-hdpi
- values-xhdpi
- values-large (5.1' 5.4' y nexus7 tablets/phones )
- values-xlarge (bigger tablets)

You can use values-sw600dp (nexus 7) and values-sw720dp(10') too.

Ah! And use sp for text, not dp. SP put the same size for all the fonts. Text Allways with SP

Remember, you allways can create values/drawables/resources in general for a lot of separate configurations: Landscape portrati, langauge, sizes, densities, night or day, version of android .... And you can merge it!

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#SmallestScreenWidthQualifier

Comment: Gave me a better understanding of how to handle multiple resolutions.

Answer (score 1):

text size should be mentioned in `sp`, not in dp try like this

```
 android:textSize="30sp"
```

Size of the text. Recommended dimension type for text is `"sp"` for `scaled-pixels`.

Answer (score 0):

make different xml layout file for tabs and phone and try this for button

```
android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can fix the size of buttons by giving weight and for the text of a button you can do this to auto size them:

```
android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="24sp"
android:autoSizeMinTextSize="20sp"
```

Set the min and max size what you need and put these codes inside a button body:)